# What ways are there to run a Bash script in VS Code, and how many user actions do they each require?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

I have this simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello, World!"
```

I love how we can can right click on python code, and run it in a Terminal.
But I can't find way to do the same for bash scripts.

Can someone help?
I open terminal tab, and copy file path, and type `./filePath.sh`.

But my goal is to find a more efficient way.

Comment: Troll: [Emacs or VS Code? Why and How I’m Slowly Switching to GNU Emacs](https://betterprogramming.pub/emacs-or-vs-code-why-and-how-im-slowly-switching-to-gnu-emacs-ea33c0837ac4)

Answer (score 3):

Hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, and begin typing in `Terminal: Run Active File In Active Terminal`.

If It says `permission denied` or similar, you may have to make it executable:

```bash
chmod +x file.sh
```

Note that this only has to be done once, if at all.

Answer (score 2):

#### `Terminal: Run Active File In Active Terminal`

There's the `Terminal: Run Active File In Active Terminal` command, which you can run from that command palette. That's either three or one user actions: It's three if you open the command palette via keyboard shortcut, type out part of the command name, and then press enter, but it's one if you [bind the command to a keyboard shortcut](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) (the command ID is `workbench.action.terminal.runActiveFile`). This will work for your case because you have a shebang in your script file. Just make sure you have execute permissions for the script (you can add such a permission with `chmod +x file.sh`).

#### Copy relative path and paste into terminal

You could just open up an integrated terminal in VS Code with a Bash shell, (which VS Code will open and navigate the current working directory to the workspace folder's path), and then just do `./relative/path/to/script.sh`. You can use command palette commands or keyboard shortcuts to open up the terminal too (`View: Toggle Terminal`, bound to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> by default on Windows and Linxu), and also to copy the relative path to the file (relative to the workspace folder) (`File: Copy Relative Path of Active File` bound to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> by default on Windows and Linux). So this is approximately four actions: copy path, open terminal, paste, hit enter.

#### Task

You can write a task for it:

```json
{
   "label": "shell",
   "type": "shell",
   "command": "${workspaceFolder}/test.sh",
   "problemMatcher": []
},
```

You can run tasks with the `Tasks: Run Task` command in the command palette, or associate a keyboard shortcut to it (`workbench.action.tasks.runTask`). If you bind a keyboard shortcut, this'll be approximately two to three actions: open the tasks selection menu, select the task (no need if it was the last task you used- that'll be selected by default), hit enter.

#### Extensions

You can also take a look at installing extensions related to Bash. One extension I've heard people use for running things (but don't use myself) is [`formulahendry.code-runner`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner). Just searching "Bash" in the Extension View, I also saw [`dominic-valerio.bash-runner`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dominic-valerio.bash-runner) <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with those  extensions)</sub></sup>.